Does Teradata have full-text search?
I've looked and looked and this doesn't even seem to be mentioned anywhere. If it doesn't how do you achieve this kind of full text query capability with Teradata? Maybe you don't?
I'm aware that there are other alternatives like OpenSearch/Elastic etc. but I'm only interested in a purely Teradata example.
I expected there to be some kind of question or example of how this might be used.

Nothing other than some sort of brute force stored proc solution, using dynamic sql in combination with the dbc views.  Which sounds like a pretty bad idea to me...
